# How to not send a data field into database Java & Microsoft Access

Tags: java, sql, ms-access

I am using Netbeans and Microsoft Access. In Microsoft Access I have 5 data fields that one of them is `ID` which is auto-number but when I use this query from Java.

```
int s= sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO stockDB VALUES('"+name+"','"+size+"','"+quantity+"','"+price+"')");
```

It shows the error:

> java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.

But the problem is that the last field is `ID` which is auto-number, but I have to send a query to the database what query should I add to the last to make it work and not disturb the ID field in the database?

Answer (score 1):

It will be useful if you use this format of `Insert` statement instead of your current statement:

```
INSERT INTO <table name> (<list of field name>) VALUES (<list of field values>)
```

> Using this format is useful when you have an `IDENTITY` or `AUTO-NUMBER` field, and when you have some fields with default values.

As a guess; your statement should be this :

```
"INSERT INTO (name, size, quantity, price) stockDB VALUES('"+name+"','"+size+"','"+quantity+"','"+price+"')"
```